# Camera preview differs from bitmap

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap, camera

I am currently creating an Android camera inside my application, however, the picture I see on the surfaceview (right before taking the image) and the captured image are slightly different, in that the captured image is cropped out.

Here is the image preview before taking the image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKocGF1ejJxX1c5Qms/view?usp=sharing

and here is the captured image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoUWREYngxWFk3aXc/view?usp=sharing

Here is the XML file for the camera preview

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the XML file for the captured image:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/capturedImageHolder"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Can anyone help?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contract that captured image will be exactly same as the preview. Actually, the camera does different jobs during preview and capture: the former is optimized for speed and battery, the latter - for image quality. There are some ways, though, you can make them more similar.

First of all, make sure that the aspect ratio for the chosen preview size is same as the aspect ratio for picture size. You may further improve your result if you choose same size for preview and picture (note that often this means that you get relatively low resolution picture).

This still does not guarantee that the images will prefectly match, because capture may involve, focusing and also there is some delay, which means that the scene will change.

You can try to keep the preview focused, and freeze the focus while capturing. I believe that this requires tuning for your specific device (which focus modes it suports, etc.) to get the best results.

Finally, you can simply use the latest preview image to store the picture instead of doing "capture". This will produce best match, but the quality of image may be worse.

Comment: I took into account what you said and implemented some of the suggestions, My image preview to captured image is quite accurate now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the preview resolution and the picture resolution are different. This is not unusual; in fact, there is no requirement that the device offer any identical resolutions between preview and picture.